# Java can't read image input file.

Tags: java, netbeans, java-io, javax.imageio, automatic-license-plate-recognition

here is the screenshot[here is the screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8kQC.png)

please help me solve this error for e to deploy our system this week.

Comment: The error message is seems pretty clear...

Comment: Can you confirm that the file exists in that path  ?

Answer (score -1):

It cannot find the file specified. The error is right there, FileNotFoundException.

Things to look into to remedy this.

1) Is the file actually there

2) Does java have access to that folder or are their access restrictions on it

3) Did you type the path correctly, looks like you are using unescaped windows style \ slashes which java doesn't like (thought it should have thrown the error earlier

Try looking at some of those errors. For more information on the FileNotFoundException https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html?is-external=true